# Check if email can be used for auth0 authentication before register/login

Tags: authentication, auth0, email-verification

Imagine an invitation based service which allows only certain email addresses to register and then login.

As developer, I would like to provide a user a simple one-input form at the very beginning of the authentication process. User provides only email address, if email is on a whitelist, user is provided with register or login form.

My question is how can I store the email whitelist and validate if email is ok to login/register before accessing login/register form in auth0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://auth0.com/docs/design/creating-invite-only-applications which gives instructions for invite only flows.

> Many SaaS apps allow self-service provisioning, where users can
>   register themselves and begin using the app. Other types of apps,
>   however, do not allow such signups. Instead, the customer (typically
>   an organization of some type) pay upfront for a number of users, and
>   only the end user with the appropriate credentials may sign up and
>   access the app. In such cases, you can use an invite-only workflow for
>   authorization purposes.